# Correct Pass Required - Training Day

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, mazes, network

I was sent a purple pass, date and venue (after my previous super secret meeting at 'No-Such-Agency'). What a day.
At Reception I presented the purple pass they sent me onto Processing, but I needed a yellow pass there.  Then back to the Canteen (red pass only) to pick up a coffee, followed by the training session at the main Meeting Room (with a Blue Pass. I kid you not). After that, it was onto Simulations (Green Pass), finishing at the test centre (with a Blue pass).  They let me out from there using a fire door! Talk about lax security!

[image]

Comment: Is there a color-blind friendly version of this puzzle?

Comment: @shoover - which CB? I’m R/G and need good light. Let me know and I will see what I can do